# PHP and Postgres: catching errors?

Tags: php, postgresql, error-handling

**How should I prepare the code if it something fails? With try-catch statement or?**

```
function delete_question ( $question_id ) {
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=heoa user=heoa password=123");

    // removes questions and its dependencies: answers and tags
    $result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn,
        'DELETE FROM questions
        WHERE question_id = $1',
        array ( $question_id )
    );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want exceptions, then you need to use PDO.

in case of pg_* functions and your code, you need to check whether $result has the value of false, if it does, then an error occured.

You can get the error description with pg_last_error()

Something like this:

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn,
        'DELETE FROM questions
        WHERE question_id = $1',
        array ( $question_id )
    );


if ($result === false) {
    print pg_last_error($dbconn);
} else {
    print 'everything was ok';
}
```

So, basically, every time you use a pg_* function, you need to check whether false was returned, that's just the way it is with those functions.

Yes, you can build your own wrappers so instead of pg_query* you call my_db_query(), which then does the return value checking and exception throwing.

Or, you could go with PDO, which is able to throw you PDOException for all the errors that can occour.

Comment: You mean I could catch pg_last_error without explicit throw-statement?

Comment: You can always wrap your own exceptions around the pg_* functions.

Comment: You don't really need the 'else' in the if-else, since throwing an exception will break you out of the function.

Comment: (referring to the pastebin link, not the above answer)

Comment: @nilamo: is it better to use break-command with error messages or throw-command with catch-command?

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Also to remove the Warring you may need to use @pg_query() and them use pg_last_error() to get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have another practice

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn,'DELETE FROM questions WHERE question_id = $1', array ( $question_id ) )
          or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
```